# Method for checking consistents of numbers in list of object

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

What I'm trying to do is make a method that will be able to figured out if some int isn't a consistent in my List of numbers (`method` should return missing numbers)

For example if I have `List<MyObject>` like this:

```
class MyObject
{
   public string Name{ get; set;}
   public int Order{ get; set;}
   public MyObject(string name, int order)
   {
      Name = name;
      Order = order;
   }
}
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>{new MyObject("1",1),new MyObject("2",2),new MyObject("4",4)};//and so on here can be even 100+ object
//or
list = new List<MyObject>{new MyObject("2",2), new MyObject("1",1), new MyObject("4",4)};
```

And now I want to `Add` some `new MyObject` to my `List` it should get missing `Order` value in this case `3`
I can make:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x=>x.Order);//this will sort my array
```

And now I'm stuck how to make program to know that there's a missing `Order` number?

I think it's clear what I want to do ( if not pls ask)

**Edit:**
Order number isn't unique.

**Thanks everyone for help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) is very helpful in this case:

```
int min = list.Min(o => o.Order);
int max = list.Max(o => o.Order);
var allNum = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1);
IEnumerable<int> missingOrderNumbers = allNum.Except(list.Select(o => o.Order));
```

Comment: Why you doing `Enumarable.Range(min,max-min+1);` ? Range always starts from 1. And `Range` returning `array` with `max` value or without?

Comment: @harry180: Because you wanted to find all missing orders between the min and max order numbers, don't you? If that's not the case you can use `Enumerable.Range(1, max)`. No, it doesn't return an array, it's similar to a `for-loop` where the loop variable starts from  `1` and ends on `max`. So no additional collection must be created.

Comment: @harry180: You're welcome. I don't know if you're already familiar with Linq. If you want just the first missing order number: `var first=missingOrderNumbers.First()`, if you want a `List<int>` with all numbers(e.g. because you want to return it from the method):  `var list=missingOrderNumbers.ToList()`. If you don't need to persist the query but just enumerate the result, use: `foreach(int num in missingOrderNumbers){//...}`.

Comment: I'm familiar with LINQ. But maybe someone in future will be not;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would suggest:

```
var max = 100;
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, max);
var intsNotInList = range.Except(list.Select(x => x.Order));
```

`intsNotInList` contains all values in `range` for which there is not a value in `list` with that `Order` value. Then, it's pretty simple just loop through these results to add them to the list.

```
foreach (var i in intsNotInList)
{
    var obj = new MyObject() 
    {
        Name = i.ToString(),
        Order = i,
    };
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first missing one then:

```
var firstMissing = list.OrderBy(x => x.Order)
                    .Select((x, i) => new {Index = i + 1, Item = x})
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Index != x.Item.Order);
```

If firstMissing is null then there are no missing items.

If firstMissing is not null then FirstMissing.Index will be the first missing item's order number that you need to insert.  Note I'm presuming you are starting the first item from 1 and not 0.

Or this will return an int which is the first missing index:

```
var firstMissingIndex = list.OrderBy(x => x.Order)
                    .Where((x, i) => i + 1 != x.Order)
                    .Select(x => x.Order - 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No need to order the entire collection to find missing orders.